# Crash of website when making https (api) requests using sockets.io

Tags: javascript, http, https, socket.io

We are facing some difficulties with a website we try to make. The website has a Javascript front end and backend. The backend uses socket.io for processing https requests through funnels. All works fine for now, but when we load test it, it slows down extremely. The site crashes before we can use it with 5 different devices. Eventually it shows an econn reset(see our error handler below).

```js
    //Doesn't stop server after crashing
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
 console.error(err.stack);
 console.log("Node NOT Exiting...");
 var datetime = new Date();
 fs.appendFile('log.txt', "\n\r"+datetime+"\n\r"+err.stack, function (err) {
    });
});
```

We also have some error handling code, but this code automatically kicks out all users of the server which results in displaying no results. We would want that this only shows up, for users who actually loose connection with the server (Hence not all other users).

See our code for making the https requests:

```js
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) 
    {
        var options = {
          host: hostUrl,
          port: 443,
          path: path,
          method: method,
          dataType: "json",
          headers: {
            accept: '*/*'
          }
        };

        var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
              var result = '';

              res.on('data', function(chunk){
                    result += chunk;
              });

              res.on('end', function(){
                    //Only send result back when its in json format
                    if(!result || result.indexOf('application/json') !== 0)
                    {
                        // preserve newlines, etc - use valid JSON
                        result = result.replace(/\\n/g, "\\n")  
                                       .replace(/\\'/g, "\\'")
                                       .replace(/\\"/g, '\\"')
                                       .replace(/\\&/g, "\\&")
                                       .replace(/\\r/g, "\\r")
                                       .replace(/\\t/g, "\\t")
                                       .replace(/\\b/g, "\\b")
                                       .replace(/\\f/g, "\\f");
                        // remove non-printable and other non-valid JSON chars
                        result = result.replace(/[\u0000-\u0019]+/g,""); 
                        
                        resolve(exstractDataForNewTemplate(JSON.parse(result)); //Make sure the results fit in the same JSON with the addToTemplate function!
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reject(null);
                    }
              });
        });
        req.end();

        req.on('error', function(e) {
          console.error(e);
          reject(null);
        });
    });
```

We would like to know how to solve this problem, either by improving the existing https request or by using an https request alternative. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please verify, that server and client version of socket.io are the same. Different version has crashed my web service once.

Comment: - edit

We tested it and apparently we had two different versions. Somehow we still have the problem though. Any other tip is more than welcome!

Comment: Sorry, no. But I know, that the client library also can be loaded from the server port, the socket.io is serving, I have currently no access to socket.io to search for the code snippet...

Comment: The code you are showing is only http handling, no socket.io code. Can you tell from the error.stack, *where* the code is crashing?

Comment: The biggest issue right now is a lot of https requests are handled at the same time when a few people use the site at the same time. Results come in very slowly or the server reset itself. (Kicks all users out of their rooms). So how can we handle a lot of https requests at once?

Comment: The request above isn't telling,, how the server is set up, what you are using there etc.The amount of http request shouldn't be a problem with the right backend. Perhaps you also have to find out, why so many http requests are necessary.